# python 3.6.3 kivy error when runing the code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, kivy

I just installed Kivy on ubuntu 17.10 with python3 version 3.6.3, when I tried to check if kivy works fine by running this code:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        # return a Button() as a root widget
        return Button(text='hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I've got this error (through vscode terminal):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pc/kivy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
  File "/home/pc/kivy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ImportError: No module named app
```

and this error (through pycharm):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pc/PycharmProjects/untitled/Kivy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you get an error when you're installing kivy?

Comment: Rename you file from `kivy.py` to something else.

Comment: No, I didn't @zeet

Comment: after changing the name of file the same error here @KlausD.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pc/PycharmProjects/untitled/text.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Hmm, interesting.

Comment: In PyCharm, do you find Kivy if you go to `File > Settings > Project: Python > Project Interpreter`?

Comment: Then kivy is not installed properly. BTW it is a different error with a different cause.

Comment: yes, but I have a problem with it, I think I have a problem with kivy installation I think it installed in the path of Python2.7 not Python3 @zeet , by the way this is the problem with kivy project interpreter
/tmp/pycharm-packaging/Kivy/kivy/include/gl_redirect.h:64:13: fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory

Comment: After I checked all dependencies and install the missing ones, while I was installing kivy project interpreter, I got this message "/tmp/pycharm-packaging/Kivy/kivy/graphics/svg.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation."

Comment: Now I downgraded cython to 0.25 and I've got a new error
"X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  4 (X_DestroyWindow)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  160
  Current serial number in output stream:  161"

Comment: I think there's a problem with the kivy directory, but I'm not sure.